# Process doesn't stop in Java

Tags: java, process, runtime, kill

I have following problem...I created a `Process` via `ProcessBuilder` in this way :

```
private ProcessBuilder processBuilder;
private Process process;

    public void init() {
        processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(
                "java", "-jar",
                "bam.jar",
                host,
        );
        processBuilder.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
        processBuilder.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
        try {
            process = processBuilder.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and I have function who should a kill process :

```
public void stop() {
    process.destroy();
    try {
        process.waitFor(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (process.isAlive()) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        process.destroyForcibly();
    }
}
```

But killing `process` sometimes work, but sometimes doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: will it give you any exception?  when the process is not stop ?

Comment: @Khalid Shah unfortunately not...

Comment: @JJJoker How do you make sure that process is not destroyed? `destroy` method is asynchronous, it is possible that process was not yet destroyed by the time you check its status.

Comment: @CrazySabbath I know that the process hasn't been closed yet because I can see in the logs that it still works and is in the task manager.

Answer (score 0):

had similar problem, resolved it by replacing `processBuilder.start()` with

```
java.lang.Process process = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("command java -jar some.jar");
proccess.destroy();
```